# WSO2 Identity server management console shows no link for STS

Tags: java, saml, ws-security, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to implement secure token service for client -> web service security authentication with WSO2 identity provider.

I downloaded and tried to work with WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 . All tutorials suggest to start with Management Console @
 < `https://testmachine:9443/carbon` >

> Home > Manage > Secure token Service. But I could not find the link for STS anywhere on management console portal. I checked for STS/SAML etc in installed features, and they all are shown fine. But couldn't find the link for STS

Am I looking at right way? Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With IS 5.0.0,  Place where you configuring the STS has been changed. You can login to management console and go through following steps.

1.Identity Provider -> List -> Resident Identity Provider

2.List "Inbound Authentication Configuration"

3.Under "WS-Trust / WS-Federation (Passive) Configuration", you can configure the policy to secure the STS service.